# How to slice vararg argument

Tags: kotlin, variadic-functions

I wrote an extension function to get an element of an JSON object by its name:

```kotlin
fun JSONObject.obj (name: String): JSONObject? =
    try { this.getJSONObject(name) }
    catch (e: JSONException) { null }
```

Now I want to extend this for nested JSON objects. I wrote the following:

```kotlin
tailrec fun JSONObject.obj (first: String, vararg rest: String): JSONObject? =
    if (rest.size == 0)
        obj(first)
    else
        obj(first)?.obj(rest[0], *rest.drop(1).toTypedArray())
```

But this looks quite inefficient to me.

What is the best way to slice a `vararg` argument?

Comment: If you're just asking about the slicing, a `vararg` is just an array, so you can use `rest.sliceArray(1 until rest.size)` to avoid converting to a list and back

Comment: @cactustictacs Using `sliceArray` is probably also not efficient. It seems to be a misnomer, because the function copies the array.

Comment: It makes a new array of the length you want and copies items into it, i.e. fills it with references to the Strings in the original array. You're not going to get much more efficient than that - what else are you expecting? What do you mean by *slice* if not copying a range of elements into another array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use vararg only in the public function, but then internally use list for recursion:

```kotlin
fun JSONObject.obj (first: String, vararg rest: String): JSONObject? = obj(first, rest.asList())

private tailrec fun JSONObject.obj (first: String, rest: List<String>): JSONObject? =
    if (rest.size == 0)
        obj(first)
    else
        obj(first)?.obj(rest[0], rest.subList(1, rest.size))
```

Both `asList()` and `subList()` don't copy data, but only wrap the existing collection. Still, this is far from ideal, because it creates a new object for each iteration and it may create a chain of views (it depends on internal implementation of `subList()`). Alternatively, the internal function could receive an array and offset - this will solve both above problems.

Generally, I suggest to not try turning Kotlin into something it is not. It has limited support for functional constructs, but it is not a functional language. Without the linked list implementation which could be easily split into head and tail, this style of code will be always inefficient and/or cumbersome. You can look for such implementation, for example in [Arrow](https://arrow-kt.io/) or [kotlinx.collections.immutable](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable). The latter has `ImmutableList` with optimized [subList()](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable/blob/75ed654e34e7111a076d87b8c075fd140e6b4cf7/core/commonMain/src/ImmutableList.kt#L48) - you can use it with the solution provided above to avoid creating a chain of lists.

**Update**

As a matter of fact, basic lists implementations in the Java stdlib also provide optimized `subList()`: [AbstractList.java](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17/blob/4afbcaf55383ec2f5da53282a1547bac3d099e9d/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/AbstractList.java#L769). Therefore, the above solution using simply `asList()` should be fine, at least when targeting JVM.

Comment: If the tailrec function is private, it can also work on an iterator.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of slicing, why don't you try just iterating over all the objects and getting the `JSONObject`s? I think this would be much more efficient.

```kotlin
fun JSONObject.obj(vararg names: String): JSONObject? {
    var jsonObject = this
    for (name in names) {
        if (!jsonObject.has(name))
            return null
        jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject(name)
    }
    return jsonObject
}
```

Comment: I was so happy that Kotlin has tail call optimization. I had to use it. ;-)